# File upload inside window.addEventListener

Tags: forms, onclick, multipartform-data, addeventlistener

My brain's hurting.  After my page loads, I get some HTML.  This is a stripped-down version:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/profile' && Cookies.get('token')) {
    axios.get('/api/profile-info').then(res => {
      const member = res.data.member
      const memberInfo = `
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadProfilePictureForm">
          <input type="file"/>
          <button onclick="uploadPicture(event)">Upload</button>
        </form>
      `;
    })
  }
})
```

I then handle the `onclick` event:

```
const uploadPicture = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const form = document.getElementById('uploadProfilePictureForm')
  console.log(form) // Just shows the HTML form
}
```

This handler is placed **before** `window.addEventListener`

The file name appears on the page, but after clicking "Upload", it won't show in the console (which I plan to send to my server).

**How do I allow an `onclick` event to handle a file upload?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Inside `window.addEventListener()`, I used a simple input tag:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="uploadPicture()"/>
```

Then, outside this event listener, I defined the `uploadPicture()` function:

```
function uploadPicture() {
  var FD = new FormData()
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileUpload')
  FD.append("pictureFile", fileInput.files[0])
  const data = FD.entries().next().value
  console.log('data\n', data) // This is the FormData array
}
```